# How to evaluate this regular expression?

Tags: regex, kleene-star

I'm just learning regular expressions, so I just want to make sure my understanding is correct.

`01*` mean 0 followed by 0 or more repetitions of 1.
`1* + 01*` means either 0 or more repetitions of 1 OR 0 followed by 0 or more repetitions of 1.

Am I right or is there something that I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: This depends on the notation you're using. `+` typically means "1 or more", not union, which is typically represented as `|`. But otherwise yes that sounds right.

Comment: A good visual tool to test your regular expressions is https://www.debuggex.com/ - It shows you in realtime what you are doing and it's very useful for building and testing regular expressions. Great learning tool too !

Comment: Yes, + is the notation I've been shown for "or", I didn't know otherwise. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems correct to me. (Even thought I'm not a whiz in regular expressiony myself)

But here's a good [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) you could check out.
[This one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) I found useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

The + in a regex doesn't mean OR but "one or more of"

So instead of 1* + 01*  you would say:

```
1*|01*
```

which would mean either a (maybe zero length) string of ones, or a zero followed by (maybe a zero length) string of ones.

So it would match any of:

```
1
1111
0
011
```

But none of:

```
101
110
100001
001
00
```

The OR operator (vertical pipe) has a low precedence.

Comment: By the way, you removed the space of the original expression `1*'_'+'_'01*` because the space is not considered as a separator.